# How to extract specific information from a dtd file?

Tags: python, dtd

In python i want to get a list of required attributes from an element as defined in a dtd file?
Is there any posibility to do this?

```
<!ELEMENT Book EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST Book
isbn CDATA #REQUIRED
title CDATA #REQUIRED
author CDATA #REQUIRED
release CDATA #IMPLIED
>
```

I want to get all required attributes to this element. "isbn", "title", and "author".

My python arrays should look like this:

```
bookRequiredAtts = {"isbn","title","author"}
bookOptionalAtts = {"release"}
```

Answer (score -1):

Parse it with [beautifulsoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). You can then [find](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#find%28name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20%2a%2akwargs%29) the attributes you want.

Here is some code to help you:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup
xml = "<!ELEMENT Book EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST Book
isbn CDATA #REQUIRED
title CDATA #REQUIRED
author CDATA #REQUIRED
release CDATA #IMPLIED
>
"
soup = BeautifulStoneSoup(xml)
soup.findAll(isbn=True,title=True)
```

Refer to the [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Parsing%20XML) for any other help.

Comment: I'm going to try this later. Thank you

Comment: I didn't find anything that worked for me. Are you sure about beautifulsoup. If so, please give me an example. I added a dtd example to my question.

Comment: I don't think BeautifulSoup can parse DTD.

Comment: It says clearly [here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Parsing%20XML) that you can use 'BeautifulStoneSoup' to parse DTD. Not all DTD, but it can be done.

Comment: I'm not trying to parse dtd. I want to get information about restrictions and names from a dtd file!